# Training accuracy decrease and loss increase when using pack_padded_sequence - pad_packed_sequence

Tags: python, pytorch, bilstm

I'm trying to train a bidirectional lstm with pack_padded_sequence and pad_packed_sequence, but the accuracy keeps decreasing while the loss increasing.

This is my data loader:

```
X1 (X[0]): tensor([[1408, 1413,   43,  ...,    0,    0,    0],
    [1452, 1415, 2443,  ...,    0,    0,    0],
    [1434, 1432, 2012,  ...,    0,    0,    0],
    ...,
    [1408, 3593, 1431,  ...,    0,    0,    0],
    [1408, 1413, 1402,  ...,    0,    0,    0],
    [1420, 1474, 2645,  ...,    0,    0,    0]]), shape: torch.Size([64, 31])

len_X1 (X[3]): [9, 19, 12, 7, 7, 15, 4, 13, 9, 8, 14, 19, 7, 23, 7, 13, 7, 12, 10, 12, 13, 11, 31, 8, 20, 17, 8, 9, 9, 29, 8, 5, 5, 13, 9, 8, 10, 17, 13, 8, 8, 11, 7, 29, 15, 10, 6, 7, 10, 9, 10, 10, 4, 16, 11, 10, 16, 8, 13, 8, 8, 20, 7, 12]

X2 (X[1]): tensor([[1420, 1415,   51,  ...,    0,    0,    0],
        [1452, 1415, 2376,  ..., 1523, 2770,   35],
        [1420, 1415,   51,  ...,    0,    0,    0],
        ...,
        [1408, 3593, 1474,  ...,    0,    0,    0],
        [1408, 1428, 2950,  ...,    0,    0,    0],
        [1474, 1402, 3464,  ...,    0,    0,    0]]), shape: torch.Size([64, 42])

len_X2 (X[4]): [14, 42, 13, 18, 12, 31, 8, 19, 5, 7, 15, 19, 7, 17, 6, 11, 12, 16, 8, 8, 19, 8, 12, 10, 11, 9, 9, 9, 9, 21, 7, 5, 8, 13, 14, 8, 15, 8, 8, 8, 12, 13, 7, 14, 4, 10, 6, 11, 12, 7, 8, 11, 9, 13, 30, 10, 15, 9, 9, 7, 9, 8, 7, 20]

t (X[2]): tensor([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]), shape: torch.Size([64])
```

This is my model class:

```
class BiLSTM(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, n_vocabs, embed_dims, n_lstm_units, n_lstm_layers, n_output_classes):
    super(BiLSTM, self).__init__()
    self.v = n_vocabs
    self.e = embed_dims
    self.u = n_lstm_units
    self.l = n_lstm_layers
    self.o = n_output_classes
    self.padd_idx = tokenizer.get_vocab()['[PAD]']
    self.embed = nn.Embedding(
        self.v,
        self.e,
        self.padd_idx
        )
    self.bilstm = nn.LSTM(
        self.e,
        self.u,
        self.l,
        batch_first = True,
        bidirectional = True,
        dropout = 0.5
        )
    self.linear = nn.Linear(
        self.u * 4,
        self.o
        )  
  
  def forward(self, X):
    # initial_hidden
    h0 = torch.zeros(self.l * 2, X[0].size(0), self.u).to(device)
    c0 = torch.zeros(self.l * 2, X[0].size(0), self.u).to(device)
    
    # embedding
    out1 = self.embed(X[0].to(device))
    out2 = self.embed(X[1].to(device))

    # # pack_padded_sequence
    out1 = nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(out1, X[3], batch_first=True, enforce_sorted=False)
    out2 = nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(out2, X[4], batch_first=True, enforce_sorted=False)
    
    # NxTxh, lxNxh
    out1, _ = self.bilstm(out1, (h0, c0))
    out2, _ = self.bilstm(out2, (h0, c0))
    
    # # pad_packed_sequence
    out1, _ = nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence(out1, batch_first=True)
    out2, _ = nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence(out2, batch_first=True)

    # take only the final time step
    out1 = out1[:, -1, :]
    out2 = out2[:, -1, :]
    
    # concatenate out1&2
    out = torch.cat((out1, out2), 1)
    
    # linear layer
    out = self.linear(out)

    iout = torch.max(out, 1)[1]
    return iout, out
```

And if I remove pack_padded_sequence - pad_packed_sequence, the model training works just fine:

```
class BiLSTM(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, n_vocabs, embed_dims, n_lstm_units, n_lstm_layers, n_output_classes):
    super(BiLSTM, self).__init__()
    self.v = n_vocabs
    self.e = embed_dims
    self.u = n_lstm_units
    self.l = n_lstm_layers
    self.o = n_output_classes
    self.padd_idx = tokenizer.get_vocab()['[PAD]']
    self.embed = nn.Embedding(
        self.v,
        self.e,
        self.padd_idx
        )
    self.bilstm = nn.LSTM(
        self.e,
        self.u,
        self.l,
        batch_first = True,
        bidirectional = True,
        dropout = 0.5
        )
    self.linear = nn.Linear(
        self.u * 4,
        self.o
        )  
  
  def forward(self, X):
    # initial_hidden
    h0 = torch.zeros(self.l * 2, X[0].size(0), self.u).to(device)
    c0 = torch.zeros(self.l * 2, X[0].size(0), self.u).to(device)
    
    # embedding
    out1 = self.embed(X[0].to(device))
    out2 = self.embed(X[1].to(device))

    # pack_padded_sequence
    # out1 = nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(out1, X[3], batch_first=True, enforce_sorted=False)
    # out2 = nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(out2, X[4], batch_first=True, enforce_sorted=False)
    
    # NxTxh, lxNxh
    out1, _ = self.bilstm(out1, (h0, c0))
    out2, _ = self.bilstm(out2, (h0, c0))
    
    # pad_packed_sequence
    # out1, _ = nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence(out1, batch_first=True)
    # out2, _ = nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence(out2, batch_first=True)

    # take only the final time step
    out1 = out1[:, -1, :]
    out2 = out2[:, -1, :]
    
    # concatenate out1&2
    out = torch.cat((out1, out2), 1)
    
    # linear layer
    out = self.linear(out)

    iout = torch.max(out, 1)[1]
    return iout, out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines of your code are wrong.

```
# take only the final time step
out1 = out1[:, -1, :]
out2 = out2[:, -1, :]
```

You say you are taking the final time step but you are forgetting that each sequence has different lengths.

`nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence` will **pad** the output of each sequence until it's length equals that of the longest so that they all have the same length.

In other words you are slicing out vectors of zeros (the padding) for most sequence.

This should do what you want.

```
# take only the final time step
out1 = out1[range(out1.shape[0]), X3 - 1, :]
out2 = out2[range(out2.shape[0]), X4 - 1, :]
```

This is assuming `X3` and `X4` are **tensors**.

Comment: ah, I see, gonna try it, thank you very much.

Comment: it works, but can you please help me understand what these do?
`out1 = out1[range(out1.shape[0]), X3 - 1, :]`'
`out2 = out2[range(out2.shape[1]), X4 - 1, :]`

Comment: First `range(out1 shape[0])` returns a "list" containing numbers from 0 to batch_size. `X_ - 1` is the length of the sequence but because of zero indexing we subtracted `1`. Then finally `:` which you can think of as all. So first for each of the samples in the batch (denoted by the first list) select the array at the same index on in the second list (which is the last output) and then select it's entire value in the last dimension.

Comment: in out_2 shouldn't it be `out2 = out2[range(out2.shape[0]), X4 - 1, :]` too ?

Comment: Oh, I see. Yeah that's how it should be. I guess I was mixing it with `X` where the first model is at index `0` and the second is at index `1`.